# $E[|X|^{2}]$ if $X \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability

How would I calculate $E[|X|^{2}]$ if $X \sim N(0,1)$?

I could use the equation for variance if it was just $E[X^{2}]$, but does the absolute value affect anything?

Comment: $E[|X^{2}|]=E[X^{2}]$ and this is easy to calculate.

Comment: What values does $X^2$ take? Does an absolute value of these numbers affect anything?

Comment: @Neutronic sorry guys, I meant if the square is on the outside

Comment: The absolute value of a number can be defined as $\sqrt{x^2}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Does this help you?

Comment: @Neutronic yes this does help me, thanks :)